# How to filter rows where key is not present in a large dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

Suppose I have a streaming dataframe A and a large static dataframe B. Assume that typically A is of size < 10000 records. However, B is a much larger dataframe with size in the range of millions.

Lets assume both A and B have a 'key' column. I want to filter rows in A where A.key is not present in B. What is the best way to achieve this.

Right now, I have tried `A.join(B, Seq("key"), "left_anti")`. However, the performance is not upto the mark. Is there anyway I can fasten up the process

Physical plan:

```
== Physical Plan ==
SortMergeJoin [domainName#461], [domain#147], LeftAnti
:- *(5) Sort [domainName#461 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:  +- StreamingDeduplicate [domainName#461], state info [ checkpoint = hdfs://MTPrime-CO4-fed/MTPrime-CO4-0/projects/BingAdsAdQuality/Test/WhoIs/WhoIsStream/checkPoint/state, runId = 9d09398b-efda-41cb-ab77-1b5550cd5da9, opId = 0, ver = 63, numPartitions = 400], 0
:     +- Exchange hashpartitioning(domainName#461, 400)
:        +- Union
:           :- *(2) Project [value#460 AS domainName#461]
:           :  +- *(2) Filter isnotnull(value#460)
:           :     +- *(2) SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, input[0, java.lang.String, true], true, false) AS value#460]
:           :        +- MapPartitions <function1>, obj#459: java.lang.String
:           :           +- MapPartitions <function1>, obj#436: MTInterfaces.Fraud.RiskEntity
:           :              +- DeserializeToObject newInstance(class scala.Tuple3), obj#435: scala.Tuple3
:           :                 +- Exchange RoundRobinPartitioning(600)
:           :                    +- *(1) SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple3, true])._1, true, false) AS _1#142, staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils$, TimestampType, fromJavaTimestamp, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple3, true])._2, true, false) AS _2#143, staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple3, true])._3, true, false) AS _3#144]
:           :                       +- *(1) MapElements <function1>, obj#141: scala.Tuple3
:           :                          +- *(1) MapElements <function1>, obj#132: scala.Tuple3
:           :                             +- *(1) DeserializeToObject createexternalrow(Body#60.toString, staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils$, ObjectType(class java.sql.Timestamp), toJavaTimestamp, EventTime#37, true, false), Timestamp#48L, Offset#27L, Partition#72.toString, PartitionKey#84.toString, Publisher#96.toString, SequenceNumber#108L, StructField(Body,StringType,true), StructField(EventTime,TimestampType,true), StructField(Timestamp,LongType,true), StructField(Offset,LongType,true), StructField(Partition,StringType,true), StructField(PartitionKey,StringType,true), StructField(Publisher,StringType,true), StructField(SequenceNumber,LongType,true)), obj#131: org.apache.spark.sql.Row
:           :                                +- *(1) Project [cast(body#608 as string) AS Body#60, enqueuedTime#612 AS EventTime#37, cast(enqueuedTime#612 as bigint) AS Timestamp#48L, cast(offset#610 as bigint) AS Offset#27L, partition#609 AS Partition#72, partitionKey#614 AS PartitionKey#84, publisher#613 AS Publisher#96, sequenceNumber#611L AS SequenceNumber#108L]
:           :                                   +- Scan ExistingRDD[body#608,partition#609,offset#610,sequenceNumber#611L,enqueuedTime#612,publisher#613,partitionKey#614,properties#615,systemProperties#616]
:           +- *(4) Project [value#453 AS domainName#455]
:              +- *(4) Filter isnotnull(value#453)
:                 +- *(4) SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, input[0, java.lang.String, true], true, false) AS value#453]
:                    +- *(4) MapElements <function1>, obj#452: java.lang.String
:                       +- MapPartitions <function1>, obj#436: MTInterfaces.Fraud.RiskEntity
:                          +- DeserializeToObject newInstance(class scala.Tuple3), obj#435: scala.Tuple3
:                             +- ReusedExchange [_1#142, _2#143, _3#144], Exchange RoundRobinPartitioning(600)
+- *(8) Project [domain#147]
   +- *(8) Filter (isnotnull(rank#284) && (rank#284 = 1))
      +- Window [row_number() windowspecdefinition(domain#147, timestamp#151 DESC NULLS LAST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), currentrow$())) AS rank#284], [domain#147], [timestamp#151 DESC NULLS LAST]
         +- *(7) Sort [domain#147 ASC NULLS FIRST, timestamp#151 DESC NULLS LAST], false, 0
            +- Exchange hashpartitioning(domain#147, 400)
               +- *(6) Project [domain#147, timestamp#151]
                  +- *(6) Filter isnotnull(domain#147)
                     +- *(6) FileScan csv [domain#147,timestamp#151] Batched: false, Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[hdfs://MTPrime-CO4-fed/MTPrime-CO4-0/projects/BingAdsAdQuality/Test/WhoIs], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(domain)], ReadSchema: struct<domain:string,timestamp:string>
```

Snapshots of query graph:

[image]

**EDIT**
 Right now I have moved the lookup data to a Cosmos DB store and created a TempView on top of it (say lookupdata). Now, I need to filter the ones that are not present in the store. I am exploring the following options:
1. create tempview on top of the streaming data as well and query
`spark.sql(SELECT * FROM streamingdata s LEFT ANTI JOIN lookupdata l ON s.key = l.key")`

2. Same as 1 but do inner sub-query instead of left anti join. i.e  `spark.sql("SELECT s.* FROM streamingdata s WHERE s.key NOT IN (SELECT key FROM lookupdata l)")`
3. Retain the streaming df as it is and do a filter op:

   ```
   df.filter(x => { val key = x.getAs[String])("key")
     spark.sql("SELECT * FROM lookupdata l WHERE l.key = '"+key+"'").isEmpty
   })
   ```

which one would work better?

Comment: Looks like neither A nor B datasets are under 10 MB for broadcast and you ended uyp with a SortMergeJoin (of two large datasets). One side of the join reads 400 CSV files from HDFS (fairly time-consuming operation), does `partitionBy` by domain with 400 (reduce) partitions (which can also be quite heavy). The LHS of the join is fairly compute-intensive so I'm not surprised _"the performance is not upto the mark"_. I think you should rethink the processing pipeline (the algorithm).

Comment: See my answer and from experience, not the way to go. Think of an airline company and the number of customers it has.

Comment: Thanks @JacekLaskowski, kindly take a look at my EDIT and let me know if this is the right way to go about it. Also, which of the 3 would work better

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import broadcast
A.join(broadcast(B), Seq("key"), "left_anti")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not the recommended approach to do this with (Structured) Streaming. Imagine you are a Chinese company with 100M customers. How do you see that working on B with a 100M rows?

From my last assignment: If large dataset for reference data evident, use Hbase, or some other other key value store like Cassandra, with mapPartitions if volitatile or non-volatile. This is more difficult though. It was no easy task the data engineer, designer told me. Indeed, it is not that easy. But the way to go.